# call jquery function in a php while loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to call a jquery function from a php while loop

my code

```
$msg_body                   =   "Test%20SMS";
while($mobList              =   mysql_fetch_array($resSet))
{
     $mobile                =   $mobList['mobile'];

     if($mobile)
     {
        ?>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() 
        {
            var mob         =   <?php echo $mobile;?>;
            var msgBody     =   <?php echo $msg_body;?> 
            var url         =   "http://example.com/abc.php?msg=TEXT&sendTo="+mob+"&message="+msgBody+"&method=sendMessage";
            $.get( url, function( data ) 
            {
                alert( "SMS SEND to : "+mob );
            });     
        }); 
        </script>
        <?php
     }
}
```

it is running for one time,  ie if more than one mobile numbers are there it will execute once and send one sms,

Alert is not working.

Comment: Remove document.ready just simply call that function in loop

Comment: What you are doing can't be done or i would say it will only work for one time because php is a server side language while jquery works on browser which means client side language. so you have a loop at server then how it will run js which belongs to the browser?

Comment: You forgot a **';'** before _var url_

Comment: @Jai — There shouldn't be any problems with generating JS statements in a loop from PHP.

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes — That's a style matter. Semi-colon insertion rules mean it isn't a problem.

Comment: @SunilPachlangia — Why?

Comment: @jai, is there any options to call an external url from php while loop,

Comment: @Ras4U — [yes](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20make%20get%20request%20from%20php&es_th=1)

Comment: "Alert is not working" — you need to do some more debugging that that in order to tell what the problem is. Look at the developer tools in your browser. Are there any JavaScript errors? Can you see the HTTP requests being made in the Net tab? Can you see the responses? Are you getting the responses you expect? (e.g. maybe you get getting rate limiting error messages because you are trying to send too many messages in too short a time from the same computer).

Comment: @Quentin how its possible?

Comment: @Ras4U — Click the link.

Comment: You could also try curl: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: One thing I noticed, which I don't think really justifies an answer so I'm putting it here:  Wrap your `mob` and `msgBody` values in quotes, so:  `var mob = '<?php echo $mobile;?>';`

Comment: Also, in order for the `alert` to work, your URL will need to return something.  If it's just processing and not sending a response, the callback will never get fired.

Comment: I checked using firebug, there is no js error.
" this request has no response data available "

Comment: @Quentin, @ Stefan

I used Curl, now its working
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I used CURL, 
now its OK

if($scm_mobile)
    {
        $ch                 =   curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 3);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        $data               =   curl_exec($ch);
    }
```